# How to prefix all the URLs of a swagger with L5-Swagger?

Tags: laravel, swagger

I am using [L5-Swagger](https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger) to build my swagger in PHP with Laravel. Can we prefix all endpoint URLs so as not to repeat them for each one? Typically the prefix "**/api/v1**" in this example:

[image]

I saw several options in `config.l5-swagger.php`, but I tried many things and failed to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this on top of your controller:

```php
/**
 *
 * @OA\Info(
 *     version="1.0.0",
 *     title="Organization",
 *     description="test description",
 *     @OA\Contact(
 *         name="test",
 *         email="test@test"
 *     ),
 * ),
 * @OA\Server(
 *     url="/api/v1",
 * ),
 */
class YourController extends Controller
```

then you have to set like this documentation for all of your controller method.

> suggestion:
> if you using PHP 8.1 or higher
> Laravel 8.x or higher
> instead of using `L5-Swagger` use `dedoc/scramble` it will generate document automatically for you and it's build on top of swagger

[https://scramble.dedoc.co](https://scramble.dedoc.co/installation)

Comment: Thanks for "scramble". I did not know. Obviously I just tried it and it’s totally magical! 0 annotation that spoil the readability of the code, and everything is there!

And what a time saver! I adopted and abandoned with l5-swagger